# I don't know how to read the PCL column detection display result

Tags: c++, linux

Cylinder detection of sample data was performed while referring to the tutorial in PCL (PointCloud Library).
Then the following result was displayed.

```
PointCloud has: 307200 data points.
PointCloud after filtering has: 139897 data points.
Plane coefficients: header: 
seq: 0 stamp: 0 frame_id: 
values[]
  values[0]:   0.0161902
  values[1]:   -0.837667
  values[2]:   -0.545941
  values[3]:   0.528862

PointCloud representing the planar component: 116300 data points.
Cylinder coefficients: header: 
seq: 0 stamp: 0 frame_id: 
values[]
  values[0]:   0.0543319
  values[1]:   0.100139
  values[2]:   0.787577
  values[3]:   -0.0135876
  values[4]:   0.834831
  values[5]:   0.550338
  values[6]:   0.0387446

PointCloud representing the cylindrical component: 11462 data points.
```

But I don't know what this result represents. What do values and the numbers next to them represent?
I am sorry for the elementary question, but I would appreciate your favor.